# FBConnect Crashes for iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

hi all
i have developed an app on Mac 10.6 with iOS 3.1.3 and i am using FBConnect for FB sharing in my app.i have already submitted the app to app store.but when i installed the application on iOS 4.1,the app crashes for FB sharing...it working fine with iOS 3.1.3.here i am not sure wahts going wrong..is it iOS issue or the FBConnect is not compatible with iOS 4.1 or something else..help me out guys...i really need to make it work....

Comment: I'm developing an app with the Facebook iOS SDK and it is working fine on all versions of iOS from 3.0 to 4.2, so there must be something you can fix in your app. What call crashes it?

Comment: thanx for the reply,as i said i have 10.6 mac and ios 3.1.3 max. so here i cant test my app for ios4..i need to upgrade my mac an ios sdk as well.but for now dont want to upgrade my system....is something wrong with the FBconnect Version?????

Comment: Why don't you want to upgrade your system? Just download the lastest SDK...

Answer (score 1):

Please write in full sentences, beginning with a capital letter, and ending with a full stop followed by a space. `..` and `...` are not acceptable ways to delineate sentences.

Are you using the latest version of the Facebook iOS SDK? If not, you can download or clone it from [Github/facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Facebook Connect was a shoddily-written bag of horseshit, but I haven't tried the new SDK. So best of luck on that!

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.my apologies,i will defenetly take care of this thing next time.

Comment: i am not using the latest SDK.My app is already there on app store.so i guess there is no way to fix it without modifying the code.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Facebook is such a pain to deal with.